# Can't correctly assign a user (Admin) to visit/acces an adminpage.php

Tags: php, authentication, admin

When i use the code in the admin.php it just doesnt give me the echo im expecting while i have the correct value in my database

I already tried searching it on google / stackoverflow but cant find any solution it just doesnt connect right. tried to put the ISSET code infront but also didnt work out.

Database:

Username / Password / Email / Role
Admin / test123 / @html.com / admin

When logged (session) it still gives me basically nothing.

```
         <?php

  include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
  include_once 'includes/functions.php';

  session_start();

  if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt, role
  FROM members
                          WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1")) {
 $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
 $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
 $stmt->store_result();

// get variables from result.
 $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt, $role);
 $stmt->fetch();

            $role = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $role);

            $_SESSION['role'] = $role;
        }


     $role = "admin";

    if(isset($_SESSION['role'])) {
     if($_SESSION['role'] == $role) {
      echo "welcome adminisn";
         } else {
       echo ("Acces Denied");
      exit();
       }

             } else {
         echo "Session not set";
               }
```

it gives me access denied
while i have the admin in my role column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume why it isn't working is because you haven't assigned $_SESSION['role'] a value when user has logged in and you do not have a statement to check if it is not assigned.

Either way this code will work:

```
    <?php
session_start(); // If we remove this then we get error Session not set

$role = "admin"; // If we change the role to something else we get access not granted


if(isset($_SESSION['role'])) {

  if($_SESSION['role'] == $role) {
    echo "Welcome admin";
  } else {
    echo("Access not granted");
    exit();
  }
} else {
  echo "Session not set!";

}
```

We need to first initialize session_start().
I am manually assigning role but you should take it from db query to check if user has admin rights or not. Then we will check if session is set. If it is not then we will display message session is not set.

If session is set we need to compare the role with user role. If it matches we get a greetings welcome admin and if role is something else we get message access not granted.

I suggest checking php manual a bit to look more into sessions. It is really easy to forget something and then the whole thing just does not work. At least that was from my previous experience.

Comment: Yo ive updated my thread could you check what went wrong? i get the access denied echo

Comment: Use print_r($_SESSION); to see what is stored in session. Also I assume you are adding all in one place as test only and later remove this $role = "admin"; which I added only for testing purpose. You should never hard core this into your script. 

Also start debugging your code to see where the system breaks using var_dump();

Answer (score 0):

Use capitals for `_SESSION`!?

```
if(isset($_session['role'])) {
```

Is this assignment correct?
What is `$role`?
If `$role` is set to `"admin"`, then admin mod is enabled for all. For all other values, it is disabled for all.

```
$_SESSION['role'] = $role;
```